# I want to create salesforce report with three objects, where two columns in my report are coming from an objects are count of a picklist value

Tags: apex, visualforce

I don't want to create separate formula fields to count the pick-list values.As I am completely new to coding , Can anyone help me how to code for this Visual-force report.

Comment: If you're new to coding, why not  start with the basics first ?

Answer (score 2):

If you are displaying the report as Table on VF page.
This just a sample code it may need lot of corrections.
I am just writing this as Idea for inital approach.

```
<apex:page contoller="sampleCtrl">
<apex:pageblocktable value="{!WrapperList" var="wl">
<apex:column value="{!wl.obj1.Name}"/>
<apex:column value="{!wl.obj2.Name}"/>
<apex:column value="{!wl.obj3.Name}"/>
</apex:pageblocktable>
</apex:page>
```

Here is the approach in your apex controller:

```
public class sampleCtr{

    //initate 3 objects with get and set them
    //query each object date into a seperate list
    //List for the wrapper class
    //Now loop through each of the list u got above and add them to the wrapper class list
    //finally you will end up with having a data from 3 diff objs in one wrapper list.
    public class wrapper{
    public Obj1 wObj1;
    public Obj1 wObj2;
    public Obj1 wObj3;
    public void wrapper(){
    this.wObj1;
    this.wObj2;
    this.wObj3;
    }
    }
```

Hope this could help to start with your coding.