# One table with multiple objects on the same row

Tags: apex, visualforce

I want to make a table that uses both a QuoteLineItem and a Product2 on the same line, but I don't think a wrapper class would work. If so I apologize, maybe I'm just overthinking it. The table would look something like this:

Headers: Product Name,  Product Code,  Quantity,  Unit Price,  Total Price

Row 1: {!prod.name}, {!prod.ProductCode}, {qli.Quantity}, etc..

Row 2: {!prod.name}, {!prod.ProductCode}, {qli.Quantity}, etc..

This would all be in an Apex:pageBlockTable, any idea how it would be done?

Comment: Wrapper class works for this. I gave an Idea on this in the follwing post you can refer it http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/67344/i-want-to-create-salesforce-report-with-three-objects-where-two-columns-in-my-r/67355#67355

Comment: it's fairly generic, but its a good start, thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to go for wrapper class in this kind of scenario. Create a list of wrapper class in the controller and add wrapper instances to it. Then in  pageblockTable, you can iterate over it and show data..

Comment: Thank you victor, how can I make it so one element of the list contains both a QuoteLineItem and a product?

Comment: You need to iterate over both lists, one inside another and then create wrapper instances.